# Movie where a woman tries to find a girl with a beetle birthmark

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a man who was a weird cat man, and a princess that hadn't been seen leaving a castle in years.

There was a woman who had to go find this girl with a beetle birthmark or something to take over the castle where all the mythical creatures lived.

I also vaguely remember someone feeding a deer in the garden.

Comment: Live action? Cartoon? When and where did you watch it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, please take the [tour] and have a read of [ask], [answer] and [help]. You're going to get an answer much more quickly if you look at [this guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and [edit] that info in.

Comment: And, as per the tour, if a correct answer is posted, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the 2008 film, *[Princess](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1052352/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2)*

As per [this review](https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/9696894):

> The story follows the life William (Kip Pardue), a former golden boy now rudderless, unemployed, and in the midst of a quarter-life crisis. While staying with an old college friend he attends a charity ball to save endangered animals that is thrown annually by a princess.
>
> The princess is the subject of rumors and gossip in the town and William learns that the mysterious Princess Ithaca (Nora Zehetner) is an eccentric who is only seen out in public once a year in sparkling tiara and fairy princess gown. She is rumored to never leave the castle and the only people seen coming in and out are old ladies.

....

> William realizes being a searcher is his destiny and returns to the castle to apologize and offer his help. Nana tells him that Ithaca has gone to find the girl and explains that the new girl must be in the castle by sunrise the next day or her powers will never develop. The girl in Ithaca's dream has braids and a beetle tattoo on her neck. He runs off in search of both Ithaca and the new girl. When he spots the new girl and tries to talk to her but she runs away.
>
> He goes to a tattoo shop to get information on the girl. There he runs into Ithaca and they learn they are looking for a homeless girl nicknamed Jitterbug (as she is jittery) and that the beetle is not a tattoo but a birth mark.

There is a scene where Ithaca is feeding a deer about 19 minutes in. And about 50 minutes in, William runs into a fellow who turns into a bestial state.

[image: Cat/Wolf Man who lives at the castle]

### Trailer

Found with a search for `film beetle birthmark`